# Closing file opened by ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I have the following:

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('connections.cfg')
sections = config.sections()
```

How can I close the file opened with `config.read`?

In my case, as new sections/data are added to the `config.cfg` file, I update my wxtree widget.  However, it only updates once, and I suspect it's because `config.read` leaves the file open.

And while we are at it, what is the main difference between `ConfigParser` and `RawConfigParser`?

Comment: Come on, documentation is your friend: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: I did read it. Couldn't find how to close it. And as for ConfigParser vs RawConfigParser, the only difference I see is some methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [readfp](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp) instead of read:

```
with open('connections.cfg') as fp:
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(fp)
    sections = config.sections()
```

Comment: [read_file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) replaced readfp now

Answer (score 35):

`ConfigParser.read(filenames)` actually takes care of that for you.

While coding I have encountered this issue and found myself asking myself the very same question:

> *Reading basically means I also have to close this resource after I'm done with it, right?*

I read the answer you got here suggesting to open the file yourself and use `config.readfp(fp)` as an alternative. I looked at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) and saw that indeed there is no `ConfigParser.close()`. So I researched a little more and read the ConfigParser code implementation itself:

```
def read(self, filenames):
    """Read and parse a filename or a list of filenames.

    Files that cannot be opened are silently ignored; this is
    designed so that you can specify a list of potential
    configuration file locations (e.g. current directory, user's
    home directory, systemwide directory), and all existing
    configuration files in the list will be read.  A single
    filename may also be given.

    Return list of successfully read files.
    """
    if isinstance(filenames, basestring):
        filenames = [filenames]
    read_ok = []
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            fp = open(filename)
        except IOError:
            continue
        self._read(fp, filename)
        fp.close()
        read_ok.append(filename)
    return read_ok
```

This is the actual `read()` method from ConfigParser.py source code. As you can see, 3rd line from the bottom, `fp.close()` closes the opened resource after its usage in any case. This is offered to you, already included in the box with ConfigParser.read() :)

Answer (score 5):

The difference between `ConfigParser` and `RawConfigParser` is that `ConfigParser` will attempt to "magically" expand references to other config variables, like so:

```
x = 9000 %(y)s
y = spoons
```

In this case, `x` will be `9000 spoons`, and `y` will just be `spoons`. If you need this expansion feature, the docs recommend that you instead use `SafeConfigParser`. I don't know what exatly the difference between the two is. If you don't need the expansion (you probably don't) just need `RawConfigParser`.

Answer (score 4):

To test your suspicion, use [ConfigParser.readfp()](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp) and handle opening and closing of the file by yourself. Make the `readfp` call after the changes are made.

```
config = ConfigParser()
#...on each change
fp = open('connections.cfg')
config.readfp(fp)
fp.close()
sections = config.sections()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `readfp` accepts a file object as argument, but your `read` accepts only a string with file path. Maybe you only forgot 2 characters in the code.

Comment: Thanks @bluish, a typo caught after 18 months is proof of relevance... The link and text were OK, now the code example is fixed.

Comment: D great! now you deservs an upvote. If you delete your comment I'll delete mine so the answer will be cleaner to read ;)