# How to loop through an output and format the result into a new report?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a script to process the output of a configuration file in a way that it results in valuable data.

The output is in the format:

```
[header]
attribute1 = integer
attribute2 = integer
[header]
attribute1 = integer
attribute2 = integer
...
```

Where there can be an unknown amount of stanzas with the same two attributes (with unknown integer values), but with different headers.

So far I have only been able to generate the number of different stanzas to use it as a loop counter, but I am not sure how to loop through the output, leave the header unchanged but sum the integer value of the two attributes and replace these with a new attribute with the sum such as,

```
[header]
new_attribute = integer
[header]
new_attribute = integer
```

I have looked into the command `read` but I am not sure how to generate the report I want with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read header &&
      read name1 equal value1 &&
      read name2 equal value2
do
    echo "$header"
    echo "new_attribute = $((value1 + value2))"
done < input.cfg > output.cfg
```

This code assumes that the input is in exactly the proscribed format. It doesn't handle erroneous input robustly: misformatted lines, missing lines, unexpected backslashes, etc.

Comment: Mr. Kugelman, what are your thoughts on [this exegesis of shell-based text processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)? I have been thoroughly shamed for applying the shell to such problems, and I hope to learn your perspective.

Comment: My own view: Stéphane Chazelas knows of which he speaks, and makes a compelling argument as to why text-processing in shell should be done *carefully* (and indeed, this answer's code *does* have numerous bugs, which the mini-essay on [unix.se] points out). OTOH, following the best practices set out in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) addresses those bugs, so it's not hopeless, but simply a case where a great deal of care is called for.

Comment: I don't subscribe to any blanket rule that forbids shell scripting for correctness or efficiency reasons. Most of the tasks I deal with involve very small text files; I hardly ever care about efficiency when parsing short config files, for instance. Awk and especially sed are, frankly, ugly tools. I use them because they're available but I have no fondness for them. Sed isn't fun to use. I care a lot about correctness and efficiency but I also care about readability and familiarity, and the shell does well on the latter two measures.

Comment: In other words, don't throw the baby out with the bath water.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the shell to process text files in bulk; it's slow and insecure. My favorite text processing tool is Awk, which you can learn more about with `man awk`.

In awk, `NR` refers to the Number Record, or line number. `%` is "modulo" or remainder, so if we know there are only three kinds of records, we can write the desired script very bluntly.

Try `awk '{print NR%3, $0}' file` to see the structure.

```
awk -F ' = ' '                                # Field Separator = space, equals, space
  NR%3 == 1 {print $0}                        # print header
  NR%3 == 2 {i=$2}                            # save second field as i
  NR%3 == 0 {print "new_attribute" FS i+$2}   # print string, field separator, and sum
' file
```

Comment: Slow, I'll grant you (typically even a well-written script in ksh93, perhaps the fastest POSIX-compliant shell available, is a full base-10 order of magnitude behind awk), but "insecure"? Only if done badly.

Comment: Consider doing `{n=(NR%3)}` up front and then `n==1`, etc. for the existing blocks of code rather than having to re-calculate `NR%3` for every block.

Answer (score 1):

Using a purpose-built library is much more robust. Especially so when compared to relying on lines appearing contiguously.

Here is a short script written in Python. It would be trivial to add tests for particular sections and attributes to ignore or pass through unchanged.

Using the input file `new.ini`:

```
$ cat test.ini
[header1]
attribute1 = 10
attribute2 = 12
[header2]
attribute1 = 23
attribute2 = 25
```

and the script `transform_ini.py`:

```
$ cat ini.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
new_config = configparser.ConfigParser()

new_key = 'new_attribute'

config.read('test.ini')

for section in config.sections():
    val = 0

    for key in config[section]:
        val += int(config[section][key])

    new_config[section] = {}
    new_config[section][new_key] = str(val)

with open('new.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    new_config.write(configfile)
```

the result is `new.ini`:

```
$ cat new.ini 
[header1]
new_attribute = 22

[header2]
new_attribute = 48
```

The script favors Mapping Protocol Access and thus requires Python 3.2 or greater. I'm not using `getint()` because it seems to be classified as part of the legacy API.

Note that `ConfigParser.read()` [closes the input file for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666375/26428).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: When I passed 100K, I received an email asking for my address, which I supplied, but I never received anything.

Comment: Seriously?  I live in Singapore, and when I filled out that form I did receive some stuff, a T-shirt, coffee mug, and a few other trinkets.  You (or maybe we) should raise a complaint about this I think.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm in the US so it's not like it fell in the ocean (assuming the origin was NY). It would have been nice to have, but I didn't get to worked up about not getting it. Although a few months later I sent a follow-up email to find out if it went missing. I never received a reply.

Comment: There is a [post on the Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329051/2019-do-six-figure-reputation-users-on-non-so-sites-still-get-swag) discussing the problem.  Apparently SO is in the process of switching swag vendors, so it might take a while before we receive anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks for finding that and letting me know.